# How to trigger click event on angular 5 with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I want to trigger `click` event based on each element `id` but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getProductsLists();
}

getProductsLists() {
  this.supplierService.getProductLists()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.productData = data;
      this.productData.forEach((value) => {
        value.prodCategoryChild.forEach((element) => {
          $('#prod' + element.id).click(() => {
            alert('This is not working');
          })
        });
      });
    });
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Where you calling this code? In constructor?

Comment: I am calling it on ngOnInit()

Comment: and UI is fully rendered?

Comment: yes it is fully rendered.

Comment: Add debugger before `$('#prod'+element.id)` and check `element.id` is not undefined and `$('#prod'+element.id)` this is making full id of your element. There is something mismatching otherwise it should work.

Comment: i've edited my question.Can you check on it sir?

Comment: Why not just handle click from html template?

Comment: First up, you shouldn't be using jQuery for accessing the DOM in Angular in the first place. Second, you can use `*ngFor` in your template and bind to the click event of each item and pass the id or index as an argument to the function that you'll be calling as your click handler.

Comment: cause i was trying to append data on every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Angular way should be like this:

```
<div-or-whatever (click)="clickHandler(prod.id)" *ngFor="let prod of productData" >{{ prod.label }}</div-or-whatever>
```

then

```
clickHandler(id) {
    alert(`Clicked prod ${id}`);
}
```